# Convergence test for series $\sum_{k\geq 0}\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\frac{\sin{x}}{x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, self-learning, trigonometric-integrals

I didn't understand the following statement made by the author in the accompanying image of a page.

"By a simple estimate $a_k\leq\frac{1}{k\pi}$ for $k \geq 1$, so $a_k \rightarrow 0$. Thus $\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin{x}}{x}dx=\displaystyle\sum_{k\geq0}(-1)^k a_k$ converges."

Now if $a_1=\displaystyle\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\frac{|\sin{x}|}{x}dx=0.43378547585$ radians. and it is greater than $\frac{1}{k\pi}$ where k=1. So this is in contradiction to the statement mentioned above.

Am i wrong in the interpretation of the above statement?

I have added second page to this question. I think the statements made by the author on this page are not correct. I want to know whether i am correct or wrong?

If any member knows the correct answer to this question may reply with correct answer.

[image: Page 1]

[image: page 2]

Comment: I don't know where you found that file, but it is out of date. The error you are pointing out was brought to my attention by someone back in April of this year and I fixed the mistake and posted a new version of the file at that time, so the file on my website has not had that mistake for many months already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality $a_k\leq\frac1{k\pi}$ is false for all $k\geq1$. I suspect that they meant to write $a_k\leq\frac1{k}$.

In fact, we can estimate
$$
a_k=\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\frac{|\sin x|}xdx
>\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\frac{|\sin x|}{(k+1)\pi}dx=\frac{2}{(k+1)\pi}.
$$
If $a_k\leq\frac1{k\pi}$ was true, we would have 
$$
\frac{2}{(k+1)\pi}<\frac1{k\pi},
$$
which is false for all $k\geq1$.

Comment: I have added second page of PDF to my question. Please check if the statements made therein by the author are correct or wrong.

Comment: @DhamnekarWinod: If my answer to the original question is satisfactory, accept my answer. Then create a new question to ask your follow up question. I would be happy to look at it.

Answer (score 0):

The integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx$ converges in sense of improper Riemann integral. But,  $\int_{0}^{\infty}\big|\frac{\sin x}{x}\big| dx$ does not converge as improper Riemann integral.

And this an example of a function which is Riemann integrable( improper ) but not, Lebesgue integrable.